# Restore trash item to original location - Linux

Tags: linux

I'm wondering if it is possible to restore a file that is in the trash (`~/.Trash`) to its original location.

I understand there is a restore command but I don't understand its arguments or how to correctly use it.

Is this a fairly simple thing to do?

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

`.Trash` is just a (hidden) directory. All you need to do is move it out:

```
mv ~/.Trash/foo ~/
```

or using the file browser of your desktop environment, open the trash and drag it out.

Comment: This is not true, under Ubuntu [MATE 16.04]. However, [these locations](https://askubuntu.com/a/102106/479118) from a 2012 answer hold true...

Answer (score 5):

If your desktop environment followed the [XDG Trash Can Specification](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec) when trashing the file, then `restore-trash` from [trash-cli](http://code.google.com/p/trash-cli/) would do the trick.

What desktop do you use?

Comment: I'm actually using Mac OS X and doing everything through Terminal

Comment: `trash-cli 0.17.1.14-2` doesn't provide the `restore-trash` command on `Linux upor 4.19.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
`. Instead, command `trash-restore` is used.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, in the trash folder (`~/.local/share/Trash/`), there is a folder with the files (`files/`) and a folder with the file information (`info/`). Each file has an associated `.trashinfo` file in which the original path and time of deletion are stored. You can use that to restore the file to its original location.

Comment: What distribution (Ubuntu, Fedora, etc.) and desktop (KDE, Gnome, etc.) are you using?  My system (RHEL 5 w/Gnome) has `.Trash` not `.local/share/Trash` and there are no `files/` and `info/` subdirectories. There is, in fact, no way to tell what the original location was.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'm using Xfce with Ubuntu, but I've seen it on Debian and Fedora systems too, not sure about the DE. Looks like my answer does not apply for this question then.